# Logic to Flip Image in jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

Anyone please explain the logic which I should use to flip image in image slider. Basically I am making a image slider, on click on any image, it should flip and behind I want to display description of that image.

I have tried examples. They are working perfectly with single image,but when I am trying in my example its not working. I know how sliding works, just explain logic to Flip image.

Just give me logic I will try write the code.

Thanks in Advance,

### HTML

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>HTML</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" type="text/css" />
    <script src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="main.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="f1_container">
        <div id="f1_card" class="shadow">
            <div class="front face">
                <img src="http://media-cdn.tripadvisor.com/media/photo-s/03/48/0b/14/dolphin-view-chalets.jpg" style="height: 281px; width: 450px;" />
            </div>
            <div class="back face center">
                Some text inside here
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

### CSS

```
#f1_container {
position: relative;
margin: 10px auto;
width: 450px;
height: 281px;
    z-index : 1;
}
#f1_container {
    -webkit-perspective: 1000;
    perspective: 1000;
}
#f1_card {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -webkit-transition: all 1.0s linear;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transition: all 1.0s linear;
}
#f1_container:hover #f1_card {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
    box-shadow: -5px 5px 5px #aaa;
}
.face {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}
.face.back {
    display: block;
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #aaa;
}
```

Comment: I would like to see the code you use for a single image, to determine your next approach.

Comment: please **provide the code that is not working**. If you don't have any code then try to copy the examples you have and then try to extend them to use multiple images. Then, if you run into trouble, **provide the code that is not working**.

Comment: Please Check ... i have provided code which works fine with single image .

Comment: I don't see the problem. Just change all the `id` to `class` and then copy + paste. [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/Spokey/ggUue/)

Comment: in the above code i have tried changing proerties like display : inline , Position :relative to make them display inline ... but its not working

Comment: Question is tagged [jQuery]. Either provide the code of remove the tag.

Comment: I was playing with code hole day just to make it Inline ... but all in vain

Comment: set property of which Element to scalex:-1?

Comment: So you want them inline like this ? http://jsfiddle.net/Spokey/ggUue/1/

Comment: ye :)    ... will go through the code to get to know the changes , thank you buddy ...   i have image slider ready just wanted this flip effect  ... thanks buddy :)

Comment: My Question was to Explain the logic used for Flip ??  i know i have the code but are there any other way   ... just tell me the logic, any other way in JQuery or CSS ??